# Failed to connect to server SMTP code: 110 Additional SMTP info: Connection timed out

Tags: wordpress

Dears,
Im trying to connect my gravity forms to SMTP MAIL and I get the following error.
My domain and email is hosted on godaddy and I have enabled authentication in godaddy.
Please help,

````
Mailer: Other SMTP
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. Failed to connect to serverSMTP server error: Failed to connect to server SMTP code: 110 Additional SMTP info: Connection timed out
Debug Output:
Connection: opening to ssl://smtp.office365.com:465, timeout=300, options=array()
Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_client(): Unable to connect to ssl://smtp.office365.com:465 (Connection timed out) [/home/xdawfds/public_html/xdaw7285h5-staging.wpdns.site/xdaw7285h5-staging.wpdns.site/xdaw7285h5-staging.wpdns.site/wp-includes/PHPMailer/SMTP.php line 397]
SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110)
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. Failed to connect to server
Source```


Mailer: Other SMTP
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. Failed to connect to serverSMTP server error: Failed to connect to server SMTP code: 110 Additional SMTP info: Connection timed out
Debug Output:
Connection: opening to ssl://smtp.office365.com:465, timeout=300, options=array()
Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_client(): Unable to connect to ssl://smtp.office365.com:465 (Connection timed out) [/home/xdawfds/public_html/xdaw7285h5-staging.wpdns.site/xdaw7285h5-staging.wpdns.site/xdaw7285h5-staging.wpdns.site/wp-includes/PHPMailer/SMTP.php line 397]
SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110)
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. Failed to connect to server
Source
````